# Energy estimate for symmetric hyperbolic systems by Friedrichs

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am currently reading A. Majda's book "Compressible Fluid Flow and Systems of Conservation Laws in Several Space Variables" and I'm stuck with the derivation of an energy principle:

> We consider a solution $v$, of the equations
> $$\tilde{A}_0 (u) \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + \sum _{j=1}^N \tilde{A}_j (u) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j} - \tilde{B}(u,x,t)v = F(x,t),$$
> $$v(x,0) = v_0(x)$$
> where we assume that $u(x,t)$ is $C^1$ and takes values in a bounded set, the matrices $\tilde{A}_0$ and $\tilde{A}_j$ are symmetric, smoothly varying in $u$ and for $\tilde{A}_0$ we have
> $$c I \leq \tilde{A}_0(u) \leq c^{-1} I$$
> for some fixed $c>0$. $\tilde{B}$ is a smoothly varying $m\times m$ matrix function of its arguments. We introduce the energy
> $$E(t) = (\tilde{A}_0(u)v,v),$$
> where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the usual $L^2$ inner product on $\mathbb{R}^N$. We set $\vec{A} = (\tilde{A}_0,\ldots, \tilde{A}_N)$ and define $\text{div} \vec A$, the matrix given by
> $$\text{div} \vec{A} = (\tilde{A}_0)_t + \sum _{j=1}^N (\tilde{A}_j)_{x_j}.$$
> Then we have
> $$\frac{\partial }{\partial t} E(t) = ((\text{div} \vec A + \tilde{B} + \tilde{B}^*)u,u) + 2(F,u).$$

First of all, I think the $u$'s in the last line should be $v$. I'm struggling how to see the last equality for $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} E(t)$. What I tried is the following: We have by the product rule
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} E(t) &= (\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\tilde{A}_0(u) v), v) + (\tilde{A}_0(u) v, \frac{\partial}{\partial t} v) \\
&= (\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\tilde{A}_0(u)) v, v) + 2(\tilde{A}_0(u) \frac{\partial}{\partial t}v,  v)\\
&= (\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\tilde{A}_0(u)) v, v) + 2(F + \tilde{B} - \sum _{j=1}^N \tilde{A}_j(u) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j},  v)\\
&=(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\tilde{A}_0(u)) v, v) + 2(F + \tilde{B} + \sum _{j=1}^N \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}(\tilde{A}_j(u) v),  v).
\end{align*}
Here, I used the symmetry of my matrices several times and integration by parts in the last step (although I'm not sure if I can do this here, maybe $v$ is bounded). This looks almost like what I want, however I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm also not sure why I'm not getting $\tilde{B}^*$ anywhere. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the $u$'s in the last line should be $v$'s.

You omitted a factor in the next to last equality; $\tilde{B}$ should be $\tilde{B}v$.
Then the $\tilde{B}^*$ comes from
$$
 2(\tilde{B}v,v) = (\tilde{B}v,v)+(v,\tilde{B}^*v) = ((\tilde{B}+\tilde{B}^*)v,v),$$
where the last step assumes everything is real valued.

You get the rest by going further with the integral by parts;
since
$$ -(\tilde{A}_jv_{,x_j},v)
 = (\tilde{A}_{j,x_j}v,v)+(\tilde{A}_jv,v_{,x_j})=(\tilde{A}_{j,x_j}v,v)+  (v,\tilde{A}_jv_{,x_j})=(\tilde{A}_{j,x_j}v,v)+(\tilde{A}_jv_{,x_j},v),
$$
you have
$$ -2(\tilde{A}_jv_{,x_j},v)=(\tilde{A}_{j,x_j}v,v).
$$
From that the rest follows.